# Connecting a database in data model fields Directus

Tags: sql, node.js, directus

I am trying to connect a collection with fields in a Data Model.
[image: This would be the collection]
And this should be the data model.I should select the key and the value should appear on right and immutable like an id.So the keys should be taken from the first photo (Nume) and the value also.
How can I do that?Can I write script for this ?I could find the location of scripts.
Thank you!
[image]